# Prevent Bootstrap from pausing javascript execution on touch scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap

i develop a webapp for the ipad using the twitter bootstrap. My Problem is that if the user scrolls the page all my carousels pause for this amount of time. This wouldn't be a problem, but i have a visualisation of the amount of time left until the next image is shown and if the user scrolls the animation is over but the next image is just appearing a few seconds later. Depending on the time the scroll took.

How can i prevent bootstrap it from doing this? or is there a simple way to pause all my js animations on touch scroll?

Comment: That's how touch scrolling works on iOS. It has nothing to do with Bootstrap specifically.

Comment: yeah i also thought that but why is the bootstrap carousel pausing and the animation to visualize the amount of time left is not pausing? I know that this makes no sense. That the reason why I'm asking this question :D